# How can we enable/disable a Azure DevOps Pipeline using Azure Devops rest api or CLI commands

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api, azure-cli, azure-devops-pipelines

I'm trying to enable/disable multiple pipelines based on a condition, would like to create a pipeline that takes the parameter from the user and updates all the other pipelines.

I've found these below documents from Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest

but I'm not able to find anything for enabling/disabling a pipeline, is there any way of doing this in any other ways?

Comment: Please check whether my answer can help you. I understand the enable/disable as run/cancel. If there is any misunderstanding, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm not able to find anything for enabling/disabling a pipeline, is there any way of doing this in any other ways?

You can use the REST API [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to enable or disable pipelines.

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=6.0
```

For its request body, you need to get the definition of the build using the GET REST API first:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=6.0
```

Use the response body of GET REST API as the request body of PUT REST API. And then modify the value of `queueStatus` according to your requirements.

If you want to enable the pipeline, set the value of `queueStatus` to `enabled`; If you want to disable the pipeline, set the value of `queueStatus` to `disabled`.

Comment: Appreciate your response, but this is not what I'm looking for. I would like to enable or disable a pipeline not to run/cancel it.
Disabling the pipeline will restrict the users to run it, Users can only be able to run the pipelines when it is in enabled state.

Options for enabling or disabling the pipeline will be present in pipeline settings, "Processing of new run requests" is the field

Comment: @karthik Sorry for the misunderstanding. I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: @karthik Hello there, not get your latest news. Is there any updates for this question?

Comment: For me this doesn't work. I `PUT` the entire json with the modified `queueStatus` parameter, but the pipeline is still enabled.